# Why perturbational approach fails to describe the bands?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, perturbation-theory, graphene, tight-binding

I'm trying to find the band structure of Graphene using tight-binding for a unit cell with 6 carbon atoms(this is a toy model for my own research). The hamiltonian is as below:
$$H=
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & - e^{i kx} & 0 & - e^{i \left(- 0.5 kx + \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{i \left(- 0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)}\\- e^{- i kx} & 0 & - e^{i \left(0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{i \left(0.5 kx + \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0\\0 & - e^{- i \left(0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{i \left(- 0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{i kx}\\- e^{- i \left(- 0.5 kx + \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{- i \left(- 0.5 kx - \frac{\\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{- i kx} & 0\\0 & - e^{- i \left(0.5 kx + \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{i kx} & 0 & - e^{- i \left(0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)}\\- e^{- i \left(- 0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0 & - e^{- i kx} & 0 & - e^{i \left(0.5 kx - \frac{\sqrt{3} ky}{2}\right)} & 0\end{matrix}\right]
$$
when I solve this eigenvalue problem and plot the band structure it gives a quadruple degeneracy at $\vec{k}=0$ and two not-tilted Dirac cones at this point which is in total agreement with expectations.
but when I expand the Hamiltonian around this point and use degenerate perturbation theory for the 4 degenerate states, I get the equation of 2 tilted Dirac cones. I used the below Hamiltonian as a perturbation Hamiltonian.
$$H^{'}=\vec{k}\cdot \nabla_{\vec{k}} H|_{\vec{k}=0}$$

I also used the wavefunctions of 4 degenerate states at $\vec{k}=0$ as the basis for degenerate perturbation theory and the acquired bands were:
$$
E_{1,2}=1.5k_x\pm3\sqrt{k_x^2+0.75k_y^2}\qquad E_{3,4}=-1.5k_x\pm3\sqrt{k_x^2+0.75k_y^2}
$$
which is definitely not correct. Does anybody know what is the problem?